# How to post this html table value into database? (Multidimensional array)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created a table so user may add item dynamically. This is the table:

```
<table>
<tr class='master_added'>
   <td>
      <input type='text' class='id_act' name='arr_item[id_act]' value='1' />
      <input type='text' class='val_status' name='arr_item[val_status]' value='SENT' />                                     
   </td>                            
   <td>
      <input type='text' name='arr_item[id_item]' class='id_item' value='ITEM_A' />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class='master_added'>      
   <td>
      <input type='text' class='id_act' name='arr_item[id_act]' value='1' />
      <input type='text' class='val_status' name='arr_item[val_status]' value='SENT' />
      <input type='text' class='id_act' name='arr_item[id_act]' value='3' />
      <input type='text' class='val_status' name='arr_item[val_status]' value='RECEIVED' />                                 
   </td>                            
   <td>
      <input type='text' name='arr_item[id_item]' class='id_item' value='ITEM_B' />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class='master_added'>
   <td>
      <input type='text' class='id_act' name='arr_item[id_act]' value='2' />
      <input type='text' class='val_status' name='arr_item[val_status]' value='DELAYED' />                                      
   </td>                            
   <td>
      <input type='text' name='arr_item[id_item]' class='id_item' value='ITEM_B' />
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to post this table value into database using a multidimensional array? Is the array I created even a correct one or easy to manipulate for loop?

This is the data after inserted to database:

```
t_item_master
ID_INSERT    ID_ITEM
1             ITEM_A
2             ITEM_B
3             ITEM_B

t_item_detail
ID_INSERT   ID_ACT        ACT_VALUE
1                1             SENT
2                1             SENT
2                3         RECEIVED
3                2          DELAYED
```

Note: I'd like to use last insert id on `t_item_master` for the `ID_INSERT` on `t_item_detail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there but. You input fields needs to specify they are arrays. You can do it by simply adding [] at the end of names, so for example:

```
<input type='text' class='id_act' name='arr_item[id_act][]' value='2' />
```

Notice `[]` in `arr_item[id_act][]` which will allow you to loop in php. For this variable you can do loop in php like this:

```
<?php 
foreach($_POST['arr_item']['id_act'] as $id_act) {
  echo $id_act;
}
?>
```

To use last INSERT ID in MySQL, you can use MySQL function LAST_INSERT_ID(). From example give here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html you can do your queries:

```
INSERT INTO t_item_detail (ID_INSERT, ID_ACT, ACT_VALUE)
    VALUES(null, value,'value'); 
INSERT INTO t_item_master (ID_INSERT, ID_ITEM)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'value');
```